# Quarkus - Open API anchors

Tags: quarkus

We are using the OpenAPI specification to create API's on an application gateway. The OAS is generated by Quarkus in combination with a static file 'openapi.yml' in the 'resources/META-INF' folder. The generated OAS merges with the static file but we lose required information.

The static file contains anchors but they are lost when Quarkus merges the static file with the generated OAS.

I've removed all other information from the OAS because it's irrelevant for this issue...

```
x-apim:
  envs:
    nonprd:
      api-gateway-host: &hst host1
      audience-id: &aud aud1
    prd:
      api-gateway-host: &hst host2
      audience-id: &aud aud2
security:
  - oidc-uni-aad: []
components:
  securitySchemes:
    oidc-uni-aad:
      type: openIdConnect
      openIdConnectUrl: URL to
      x-kong-security-openid-connect:
        config:
          audience_required: [*aud]          
x-kong-route-defaults:
  hosts:
    - *hst
```

Expected output:

```
x-apim:
  envs:
    nonprd:
      api-gateway-host: &hst host1
      audience-id: &aud aud1
    prd:
      api-gateway-host: &hst host2
      audience-id: &aud aud2
security:
  - oidc-uni-aad: []
components:
  securitySchemes:
    oidc-uni-aad:
      type: openIdConnect
      openIdConnectUrl: URL to
      x-kong-security-openid-connect:
        config:
          audience_required: [*aud]          
x-kong-route-defaults:
  hosts:
    - *hst
```

Actual output:

```
x-apim:
  envs:
    nonprd:
      api-gateway-host: host1
      audience-id: aud1
    prd:
      api-gateway-host: host2
      audience-id: aud2
x-kong-route-defaults:
  hosts:
  - hst
```

As you can see, the '&' and '*' anchors are missing.

Any ideas?